# How to use diff while doing wget?

Tags: wget

Let's say there is a site www.songs.com, I download songs from that site using wget -r. Then,say , 3 days later, there has been an update on the site and new songs have been added.

> Is there any way I download only new songs using wget?

As it stands, if I give command

> wget - r

It will download the whole website.

Comment: you are looking for an rsync that is http based, right?

Comment: @ThorstenStaerk, I have heard of Rsync, but not ever used it. From what I know, Rsync is a diff tool. So in a broader sense, that is what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can try using `wget --no-clobber`, but as mentioned above, you probably want to look into using a solution that is based on `rsync` rather than HTTP.  Presuming that you have SSH access to the server, `rsync` can use that as a transport mechanism with `rsync -za --stats -essh user@host.example.com:/path/to/files /path/to/local/copy/of/files`.

Note though that `wget --no-clobber -r` will only get files that are *new* since the last check, and won't re-download new copies that have *changed*.  That's why `rsync` is the better solution for the use-case you present.

Another alternative I found is the GPL software, HTTrack, which mirrors entire web sites, and can pull down subsequent differentials.  It can be found [here](http://www.httrack.com/page/2/en/index.html).  Windows screen shot, but there are builds and/or source for Windows, OS X, Linux, BSD, and Android(!).

Comment: No I don't have the ssh access. I am talking about a general blog or music website.

Comment: I guess then `wget -r --no-clobber` is what you need, though you might want to be sure it's okay with the maintainer of the site that you're crawling and cloning it. (:

Comment: @JoeDimaggio, I've found another solution that might be something you could use.  See above.

Comment: But, if in my case, only new files are being added, then wget -no clobber will work, right>

Comment: Yes, that should work as you need.